# How can you find the determinant of the following matrix in python? A = np.array([[1-'a'-'y','a'],['b', 'y']])

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to find the determinant of the following matrix but I get a syntax error when I try to define the matrix. Can someone tell me how to define a matrix whose elements are variables and numbers? Here's what I have:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1-'a'-'y','a'],['b', 'y']])
```

Comment: Seems you are calling variables as strings. I assume `a`, `b`, and `y` are variable names. So you should have `A = np.array([[1-a-y, a], [b, y]])`.

Comment: I don't see variables.  I see strings.  `'a'-'y'` is probably giving you the error, since you can't subtract one string from another.  There is a separate package that lets you do define symbols and do algebra, `sympy`.

Comment: You seem to want to represent variables (a, b and y) as strings in python and then expect numpy to solve this system of equations. This is not the case at all. You can easily solve for the determinant of any 2x2 matrix yourself and solve for the relationship between a, b and y. The choice to use python for symbolic algebra is not something you will want to currently do.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you're trying to do math on strings and numbers. That doesn't work: they're different, incompatible, data types.

If you want to do "symbolic computation" (rearranging symbols rather than using actual numbers) in Python, you'll want the `sympy` library.

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix

a, b, y = symbols(['a', 'b', 'y']) # Turn a, b, y into symbolic variables
A = Matrix([[1-a-y, a], [b, y]]) # Define the matrix
print(A.det()) # Print its determinant
# Prints "-a*b + y*(-a - y + 1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple cases, such as computing determinant of 2x2 matrix, you can use the following approach:

```
def get_det(array, **kwargs):
    det_eq = '(' + array[0][0] + ')' + '*' + '(' + array[1][1] + ')'\
              + '-' + '(' + array[0][1] + ')' + '*' + '(' + array[1][0] + ')'
    locals().update(kwargs)
    return eval(det_eq)



get_det(array, a=1, b=3, y=3)
# -12
```

Note: using `eval` is unsafe; So, you need to be sure about safety of the array's content.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same question and came across these two answers. I'm just joining the proof and the math operation done in the sympy library.
So we create a 3x3 matrix and then we pass a variable to it, note that to add a variable and be able to determine its value we must use the Matrix() entity of Sympy. It is only possible to deal with these symbols with the help of a logic that sympy has contained in the source, which mathematically relates variables and logical and mathematical operators.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, Symbol
#a, b, k = symbols(['a', 'b', 'k'])
k = Symbol('k')

u = np.array([2, -1, k])
v = np.array([1, 0, 2])
w = np.array([k, 3, k])

z = [u, v, w] #axis with variables

#A = Matrix([u , v, w])
A = Matrix(z)
print(A.det())#must be square matrix
#here, the awnser is 6. Six is the proof value
#for the equation generated by sympy mathing 'symbols'(variable) and values
#notice that we actually still need to
#isolate the k variable
determin = np.array([[2, -1, 6], [1, 0, 2], [6,3,6]])
d = np.linalg.det(determin)#must be square matrix

print(d)
```

the output

```
2*k - 12
0.0
```